# query send by jquery.load() function to Controller receiving as list of objects containing null values

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

[image]
My controller return a query in response of a ajax call

```
return Json(new { success = true, query1 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I receive the result in success function of ajax call. I need to send this `query1` to `.load` fuction like this:

```
 success: function (response) {
                alert("success");
                var flag2 = "Query";
  $("#worker").load("/Worker/AjaxPage", { Flag: flag2, Result:response.query1 });
            },
```

But i receive the flag and query in my controller but all the objects members contain null data. But `Result` contain same number of objects as `query1` have . But all data is null

controller code:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [UserAuthorize(Roles = "1, 3")]
        public ActionResult AjaxPage(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, string[] Name, string[] WorkerNo, string[] Group, string[] Department, string Status, string StartDate, string EndDate,string Flag,List<WorkerViewModel> Result)
        {
            if (Flag == "Query")
            {

                return PartialView("_PartialAjaxPage", Result);
            }
            if (Flag=="Filter")
            {
                using (db = new BiaqmEntities())
            {
                var query = (from w in db.workers
                             from c in db.BsysCountryLists.Where(c => c.ID == w.CountryID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                             from f in db.farms.Where(f => f.id == w.farm_id).DefaultIfEmpty()
                             from comp in db.companies.Where(comp => comp.id == w.company_id).DefaultIfEmpty()
                             from ig in db.InputGroups.Where(ig => ig.ID == w.InputID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                             select new WorkerViewModel
                             {
                                 id = w.id,
                                 Name = w.name,
                                 engName = w.name_eng,
                                 WorkerNumber = w.WorkerNumber,
                                 IDNumber = w.id_card_numder,
                                 DOB = w.birth.Value,
                                 Country = c.SHORT_NAME,
                                 Cell = w.CelPhone,
                                 StartWorkingDate = w.start_date.Value,
                                 Email = w.Email,
                                 EndDate = w.EndDate,
                                 Companyid = comp.id,
                                 Farmid = f.id,
                                 CompanyName = comp.name,
                                 FarmName = f.name,
                             });

                var Namequery = query;
                var Workerquery = query;
                var Groupquery = query;
                var Departmentquery = query;
                var Activequery = query;
                var Inactivequery = query;
                var StartDateQuery = query;
                var EndDateQuery = query;
                if (StartDate != "")
                {
                    var dates = StartDate.Split(new char[] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    var startDate1 = DateTime.Parse(dates[0], CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                    var startDate2 = DateTime.Parse(dates[1], CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                    StartDateQuery = query.Where(w => w.StartWorkingDate >= startDate1 || w.StartWorkingDate <= startDate2);
                }
                if (EndDate != "")
                {
                    var dates2 = EndDate.Split(new char[] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    var EndDate1 = DateTime.Parse(dates2[0], CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                    var EndDate2 = DateTime.Parse(dates2[1], CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                    EndDateQuery = query.Where(w => w.EndDate >= EndDate1 || w.EndDate <= EndDate2);
                }
                if (Name != null)
                {
                    if (Name.Length > 0)
                    {
                        List<string> NameList = new List<string>(Name);
                      Namequery = query.Where(w=>NameList.Contains(w.Name));
                    }
                }
                if (WorkerNo != null)
                {
                    if (WorkerNo.Length > 0)
                    {
                        List<string> WorkerNoList = new List<string>(WorkerNo);
                         Workerquery = query.Where(w => WorkerNoList.Contains(w.WorkerNumber));
                    }
                }
                if (Group != null)
                {
                    if (Group.Length > 0)
                    {
                        List<string> GroupList = new List<string>(Group);
                         Groupquery = query.Where(w => GroupList.Contains(w.Group));
                    }
                }
                if (Department != null)
                {
                    if (Department.Length > 0)
                    {
                        List<string> DepartmentList = new List<string>(Department);
                         Departmentquery = query.Where(w => DepartmentList.Contains(w.Department));
                    }
                }
                if (Status == "Active" || Status == "Inactive")
                {

                    var condition1 = query.Where(j => j.StartWorkingDate == null || j.StartWorkingDate < DateTime.Today);
                    var condition2 = query.Where(e => e.EndDate == null || e.EndDate > DateTime.Today);
                    if (Status == "Active")
                    {
                        Activequery = condition1.Intersect(condition2);

                    }
                    if (Status == "Inactive")
                    {
                        Inactivequery = query.Except(condition1.Intersect(condition2));

                    }
                }
                if (Status == "Active")
                {
                    query = Activequery;

                }
                else if (Status== "Inactive")
                {
                    query = Inactivequery;

                }
                else
                {

                }
                if (Name != null)
                {
                    query = query.Union(Namequery);
                }
                if (WorkerNo != null)
                {
                    query = query.Union(Workerquery);
                }
                if (Group != null)
                {
                    query = query.Union(Groupquery);
                }
                if (Department != null)
                {
                    query = query.Union(Departmentquery);
                }
                if(StartDate!="")
                {

                    query = query.Union(StartDateQuery);
                }
                if (EndDate != "")
                {

                    query = query.Union(EndDateQuery);
                }

               var  query1 = query.ToList();
                return Json(new { success = true, query1 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            }
            else
            { 
                //do some thing
               }
            }

        }
```

> script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#Refresh').click(function () {
            alert("im hit");
            var FilterName = [];
            //items = '';
            $('#FLName option:selected').each(function (i) {
                FilterName.push($(this).val());
            });
            //for (var i = 0; i < FilterName.length; i++) { items += ' ' + FilterName[i] };
            //alert(items);
            //var FilterName =$("#FLName").val();
            var FilterWorkerNo = [];
            $('#FLWNo option:selected').each(function (i) {
                FilterWorkerNo.push($(this).val());
            });
            var FilterGroup = [];
            $('#FLGroup option:selected').each(function (i) {
                FilterGroup.push($(this).val());
            });
            var FilterDepartment = [];
            $('#FLDepartment option:selected').each(function (i) {
                FilterDepartment.push($(this).val());
            });
            var FilterStatus = $("#FLStatus").val();
            var FilterStartDate = $("#FLSDate").val();
            var FilterEndDate = $("#FLEDate").val();
            var flag = "Filter";
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("AjaxPage", "Worker")",
                type: 'POST',
                traditional: true,
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    sortOrder:"",
                    currentFilter:"",
                   searchString:"",
                Name: FilterName,
                WorkerNo: FilterWorkerNo,
                Group: FilterGroup,
                Department:FilterDepartment,
                Status: FilterStatus,
                StartDate: FilterStartDate,
                EndDate: FilterEndDate,
                Flag:flag
                }),
            dataType: "text json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
                alert("success");
                var flag2 = "Query";
                $("#worker").load("/Worker/AjaxPage", { Flag: flag2, Result: response.query1 });
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                alert("fail");
            }
        });


        });





    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is there something missing from this `return Json(new { success = true, query1 = ?????? }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); `

Comment: ^^ as pointed out.. you just have a property to which the value is not assigned.. hence it contains nothing.. that is `undefined`

Comment: there is no problem from json return . query1 is List<workerViewModel> type: check the image attached

Comment: @Ammartahir you cannot pass data like that.. use this `return Json(new { success = true, query1 = query1  }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` your object must have a `property-value` relationship..

Comment: now check the code of if(flag=="Filter") {.......long logic ....return Json(new { success = true, query1 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);}

Comment: @Ammartahir you are not changing the part which I am asking you to... REPLACE `query1`  with `query1 = query1` . This way the property name is also a `query1` and value is assigned to it from the variable `query1`

Comment: @Reddy tried your solution but no effect . i believe there is some problem with   $("#worker").load("/Worker/AjaxPage", { Flag: flag2, Result: response.query1 });

Comment: @Ammartahir I dont see any other issue apart from the one I mentioned.. can you do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(response.query1))` once you fetch the data and let me know what you see ?

Comment: @Reddy  its print out 9 objects contain by query1

Comment: @Ammartahir oh!!! I am not sure what else might be the issue.. how ever you can pass this stringified data (which is of data type string) to your controller and there you can deserialize into the required object.. Can you try that

Comment: What in the world are you trying to do here? Why do you have an ajax call that returns the data you need to update the view, but then ignore it and in the success callback make another ajax call (using `.load()` to send all the data you received back to the controller again)

Comment: @Reddy thanks ready you finally solved it

Comment: @Ammartahir glad you got it working.. Also as Stephen points out.. you are just passing data from controller to ajax call and back to controller from ajax call.. There is a lot of data transferred .. May be you can think of a better approach to negate this data transfer..

Answer (score 0):

> In script i changed my object to json.stringyfy

```
var str = JSON.stringify(response.query1);
                $("#worker").load("/Worker/AjaxPage", { Flag: flag2, Result: str });
```

> And in controller i get the **Result** as string type and use Newtonsoft.Json for deserializing.
>   For Deserializing help :https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/79435/Deserialize-JSON-with-C
>   Controller change:

```
 public ActionResult AjaxPage(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, string[] Name, string[] WorkerNo, string[] Group, string[] Department, string Status, string StartDate, string EndDate,string Flag,string Result)
        {
            if (Flag == "Query")
            {
                if (Result != "")
                {
                    List<WorkerViewModel> Deserialobj = (List<WorkerViewModel>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Result, typeof(List<WorkerViewModel>));
                    return PartialView("_PartialAjaxPage", Deserialobj);
                }



            }
 ///////// remaining code
```

}